# Concurrent select in sqlite is very slow

Tags: c++, database, multithreading, sqlite, concurrency

When I execute SELECT query on single sqlite database, reading speed from my hdd reach almost ~200 MB/s. When I try to open 8 sqlite files simultaneously, run 8 threads and each of thread execute select for single sqlite, reading speed decrease to ~20 MB/s. Why is that so? Each sqlite I use as single-thread mode with "journal_mode = wal" and "synchronous = off". Do you have any idea? Thank you.

Comment: I'd expect trying to read from 8 files on the same drive at the same time to be slower than reading one. The [thread mode](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) being used makes a difference too... Make sure you're using multithread and not serialized.

Comment: I meant the ~20 MB/s as whole bandwidth, not for one file. While reading single file, reading speed from disk is ~200 MB/s, while reading multiple files at time, reading speed from disk is ~20 MB/s. It looks like to some kind of lock occuring. I try open sqlite files on single-threaded mode and also for multithreaded-mode. Both are without change.